# How to specify what page a URLFOR Action calls

Tags: apex, visualforce, urlfor

I have a visualforce page that basically saves a contact object but can be accessed from two different pages. I have this command button:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Done" id="doneButton" immediate="true" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.view, linkedObjectId)}"/>
```

In my controller I have the following pageReference code:

```
public PageReference saveAndAssign(){
    check = true;

    try {
        newRelatedContact.Related_Person__c = RS_ContactUtils.create(newContact);
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        check = false;
    }

    if(check){          
        insert newRelatedContact;       
        newContact = new Contact();
        newRelatedContact = new RS_Related_Contact__c();
        this.newRelatedContact.put(relatedObjectField, linkedObjectId); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, when i click the done button, I get the error:

> Error is in expression '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.view, linkedObjectId)}' in component  in page arcusregserv:rs_relatedcontactsdefine

The record saves but i get the error page first. is there a work around in the URLFOR for this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

URLFOR is normally used in an `apex:outputLink`; an `apex:commandButton` is normally bound to a controller method:

```
<apex:commandButton ... action="{!saveAndAssign}"/>
```

If your aim is to first invoke the `saveAndAssign` controller method and then go to the Account view page, then the other change to make is to return the new page reference from that method:

```
public PageReference saveAndAssign() {
    ..
    return new ApexPages.StandardController(linkedObjectId).view();
}
```